# Gradle packagingOption, pick other than first

Tags: android, gradle, mobile-development

I'm facing a situation where some packages import the same native library:

```
   > 2 files found with path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so' from inputs:
      - ~/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7d9d92dc8ec1ba2e45aff2ecbb549550/transformed/jetified-react-native-0.68.2/jni/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so
      - ~/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/e21c7f468f769020a3f8f2f5f3ed5664/transformed/jetified-libvlc-all-3.3.10/jni/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so
```

The standard solution is to use pickFirst:

```
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
    }
```

The thing is that, in my example as seen above, "first" here is the react-native file. I want to pick the libvlc file.

As far as I know, I can't exclude files based on the source package name.

How can I tell gradle to "pickLast" or "pickSomethingElseThanFirst"?

Thank you

Comment: Have you found any solution to this?

Comment: Actually, I found my own answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74279439/4957634

Answer (score 0):

You can see all options here in documenttion:https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/3.2/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html

Packaging options are configured with three sets of paths: first-picks, merges and excludes:

First-pick

> Paths that match a first-pick pattern will be selected into the APK.
> If more than one path matches the first-pick, only the first found
> will be selected.

Merge

> Paths that match a merge pattern will be concatenated and merged into
> the APK. When merging two files, a newline will be appended to the end
> of the first file, if it doesn't end with a newline already. This is
> done for all files, regardless of the type of contents.

Exclude

> Paths that match an exclude pattern will not be included in the APK.